# How can I fix my button positions on my html,css,js,php website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a website, where i have some images and buttons, the problem is when  I perfectly alligned the buttons their position changes on different resolutions and for me it looks good but for someone on laptop it looks awful. Same thing is when trying to do it for mobile resolution (everything is just messing up).

[Good placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIW93.png)

[Bad placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C02yi.png)

[Even worse placement on mobile](https://i.imgur.com/JefC7ay.png)

**HTML HERE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Grzegorz</title>   
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- Additional tags for responsive design -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grzesiu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testers.css">
</head>


<body>
    <!-- Background Layers -->
        <div class="mobile-message">
            <p>We are sorry. This site is currently unavailable on mobile.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bg_png" class="background-layer"></div>
        <div id="bg_png1" class="background-layer"></div>
        <div id="bg_png2" class="background-layer"></div>
        <div id="bg_png3" class="background-layer"></div>
        <div id="bg_png4" class="background-layer"></div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <button class="nav-button" onclick="window.location.href='./support.php';"><b>SUPPORT</b></button>
            <button class="nav-button2" onclick="window.location.href='./subscriptions.php';"><b>ABOUT</b></button>
    
             <?php
                session_start();
                if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
                    echo '<button class="nav-button3" onclick="window.location.href=\'../logout.php\'"><b>LOGOUT</b></button>';
                } else {
                    echo '<button class="nav-button3" onclick="window.location.href=\'../login.php\'"><b>LOGIN</b></button>';
                }
                ?>
        </div>
            <div id="learnmore">
                <button class="nav-button4" onclick="smoothScroll('#bg_png6');"><b>LEARN MORE</b></button>
            </div>
            <!-- JavaScript (if needed) -->
    <script src="scripto.js"></script>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Array of background elements
  var backgroundElements = [
    'bg_png', 'bg_png3', 'bg_png4',
  ];

  // Function to set background styles
  function setBackgroundStyles(elementId, imageUrl, zIndex) {
    var bgElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
    bgElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    bgElement.style.top = '0';
    bgElement.style.left = '0';
    bgElement.style.width = '100%';
    bgElement.style.height = '100%';
    
    bgElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + imageUrl + '")';
    bgElement.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    bgElement.style.backgroundPosition = 'center top';
    bgElement.style.zIndex = zIndex;
  }

  // Hide the GIF after a delay (e.g., 3 seconds)
  setTimeout(function() {
    setBackgroundStyles('bg_png1', 'https://i.imgur.com/IlmUjKY.png', '-15');
    setBackgroundStyles('bg_png3', 'https://i.imgur.com/NsTp7fS.png', '-15');
    setBackgroundStyles('bg_png4', 'https://i.imgur.com/5ymR224.png', '-16'); // Lower z-index for bg_png4
    // Repeat for the remaining elements

  }, 3000); // Adjust the delay as needed  
});


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS HERE**

```
/* Resetting default styles */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#gifContainer {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}
button{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
}
/* General background layer styles */
.background-layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.mobile-message {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none; /* initially hidden */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .mobile-message {
        display: flex;
    }

    .background-layer, #content {
        display: none;
    }
}
#bg_png {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  z-index: -17;
}
/* Content layer styles */
#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Styling the navbar and buttons */
#navbar {
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
#learnmore {
    position: absolute;
    top: 690px;
    right: 430px;
}

.nav-button {
    /* Text Styles */
    margin-right: 22px;
    color: #ff4e00;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Dark Purple Background */
    background: #FFFFFF;

    /* Shadow Effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    /* Transition for Hover Effect */
    transition: background 1s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: -3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
}

.nav-button:hover {
    /* Hover Effect: Lighter Background */
    background: #282828;

    /* Hover Effect: Lift Button */
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav-button2 {
   /* Text Styles */
    margin-right: 50px;
    right: 3px;
    color: #ff4e00;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Dark Purple Background */
    background: #FFFFFF;

    /* Shadow Effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    /* Transition for Hover Effect */
    transition: background 1s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: -3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
}

.nav-button2:hover {
    /* Hover Effect: Lighter Background */
    background: #282828;

    /* Hover Effect: Lift Button */
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.nav-button3 {
   /* Text Styles */
    margin-right: 50px;
    right: 32px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Dark Purple Background */
    background: #ff4e00;

    /* Shadow Effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    /* Transition for Hover Effect */
    transition: background 1s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: -3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
}

.nav-button3:hover {
    /* Hover Effect: Lighter Background */
    background: #282828;

    /* Hover Effect: Lift Button */
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.nav-button4 {
   /* Text Styles */
    right: 32px;
    top: 620px;
    color: #ff4e00;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Dark Purple Background */
    background: #FFFFFF;

    /* Shadow Effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    /* Transition for Hover Effect */
    transition: background 1s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: -3px;
    width: 175px;
    height: 45px;
}

.nav-button4:hover {
    /* Hover Effect: Lighter Background */
    background: #282828;

    /* Hover Effect: Lift Button */
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Responsive design for smaller screens */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    width: 80%; /* On smaller screens, the dropdown takes a larger percentage of the width */
  }
}
```

I have tried different positions so, absolute, relative, , adding @media to fix it for different resolutions and nothing worked for me. Hope you guys will help me achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your browser window for the purpose of your tests. Therefore, your first task is to temporarily separate the issue.

Implement a solution for the first screen size, then one for the second, then for the third.

You will need to find out how distant these versions are from each-other. If you can differentiate them only with CSS, then you can solve your issue with media queries only.

If not, then you will need to develop separate structures. In the worst-case scenario you would have a page where at load/resize time the screen would be measured and the appropriate view displayed.

But it would be great to marry all three versions appropriately and have CSS-only differences. Maybe implementing it from scratch would help.